# Is GNU PDF Library in active development?

Tags: development, pdf, gnu

I've been hearing about [The GNU PDF Library](http://www.gnupdf.org) since [2007](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/122195). Since then I've been looking forward to see this tool in the wild, but four years have passed and it seems to me that this is a painfully long time. I'm aware of the complexities of the project, but as I recall the GNU Foundation have marked it as a top priority project. What is going on?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some activity on http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/pdf-devel/. Also, see http://gnupdf.org/manuals/gnupdf-hg-manual/html_node/Information-for-Newcomers.html#Information-for-Newcomers for information about cloning their repository. Specifically do

```
 $ bzr branch bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/pdf/libgnupdf/trunk libgnupdf
```

[Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) is a distributed version control system, and its command line client is called `bzr`.
Looking at the repository is a good way to determine activity. You can see the logs by changing directory into the repository `libgnupdf` and doing `bzr log -v | less`. My two cents are that 929 revisions in slightly less than 4 years isn't so bad. Such projects usually have a shortage of manpower and of course everyone is a volunteer. If you have any specific questions, I'm sure the developers would be happy to answer, as long as you ask nicely.

Comment: I know some people are going to crucify me for this I'm about to say: I think the choice of "plain" C as the programming language for this project has complicated things a lot. I know that everybody wants a fast library, but IMHO I prefer an _existing_ yet not-so-fast one than an inexistent fast one. I would have voted for Python. Now let the nails come!

Comment: @Sergio: Actually, I'd be inclined to agree with you, but... Were they perhaps concerned about stability? Python isn't exactly static, and they'd eventually have to worry about making their code work with Python 3. I don't know if speed is so much the issue. Could they not have written just the hot-spots in C?

Comment: This is certainly an issue, although I think Python is pretty stable right now. Many projects are perfectly OK with pre 3.0 python. I agree with you that C doesn't change a lot these days. I still stick to my previous opinion on this.

Comment: C is ideal for a library because bindings can be provided for just about every language. I don't think there is another reasonable choice for this, is there?

Comment: @Don: If you write for GNOME then there is also Vala.

Comment: Most of the activity on the mailing list is newbies offering help.

Answer (score 3):

The FSF has recently dropped GNU PDF from their list of priority projects because libraries like [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), [podofo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/), [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) and [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) have developed quite nicely over the last years. Given the speed of development of GNU PDF over the last years I'm tempted to call it glacial: They seem to spend all their time at building foundations and up to now don't seem to have at least a minimal parser. It seems [GNU Hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/) will be finished before GNU PDF.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210029/821436) for a list of PDF libraries.

Comment: Link to list of PDF libraries is broken.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Faheem answer - it is good to look on [Ohloh](http://ohloh.net) stats (here is [GNU PDF Ohloh page](http://www.ohloh.net/p/gnupdf)). It sees that project have steady growth and while it have not increasing year-to-year development it is not dieing out as well (which is good).

Ohloh of course is just visualization of bazaar but I believe that "a picture is worth a thousand words".